# How to get UIPageViewcontroller Page Index values and names?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to get `pageviewcontroller` current `index` value and name based on that I will make one `alert` with view controller name also. i don't know how to get that one.

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement below method of `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`.

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
```

It will return the index of selected page.

Comment: - (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return self.contentPageRestorationIDs.count;
} Its already Have but how to get current page Index value and names?@Apurv